# How to add the strings in a particular line without hardcoding

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, shell, command-line

I have 2 files, 1st file it has the output and another one template. I want to add ID's in the template from output without hardcode the value.

```
 Output.txt,
      abc  8392382222
      def  9283923829
      ghi  2392832930

Template file,
    Pool : 1
      Some text
      Some text
      Some text
      name:
      no:
      London
      UK
      name:
      no:
      London
      UK
      name:
      no:
      London
      UK

    Pool : 2
      Some text
      Some text
      Some text
      name:
      no:
      London
      UK
      name:
      no:
      London
      UK
      name:
      no:
      London
      UK
```

I want to add output lines in template like below

```
    Pool : 1
      Some text
      Some text
      Some text
      name: abc
      no: 8392382222
      London
      UK
      name: def
      no: 9283923829
      London
      UK
      name: ghi
      no: 2392832930
      London
      UK

    Pool : 2
      Some text
      Some text
      Some text
      name: abc
      no: 8392382222
      London
      UK
      name: def
      no: 9283923829
      London
      UK
      name: ghi
      no: 2392832930
      London
      UK
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just bash, you can read two files simultaneously: just redirect on of it to a different file descriptor.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while read -r -a values ; do
    for i in {0..3} ; do
        read -u 3 line
        echo "$line ${values[$i]}" 
    done
done < output.txt 3<template.txt
```

Note that usually, the template file contains just the four lines that should repeat, so you can read it into an array *before* processing the file containing values, so you don't need any additional descriptors:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
template=()
while read -r line ; do
    template+=("$line")
done < template.txt

while read -r -a values ; do
    for (( i=0; i<${#template[@]}; ++i )) ; do
        echo "${template[$i]} ${values[$i]}" 
    done
done < output.txt
```

Comment: I tried both the scripts, It is displaying the output but it is not added into template file.

Comment: @Beginner: Just redirect the output to a temporary file, then `mv` the temp file to the template.

Comment: but still I  need to do lots of things. Could you please help me. can we have a call

Comment: I'm too busy, sorry. This site is great if you want to learn, if you just need a solution, hire someone to help you.

Comment: Could you please look now

Comment: Changing the question to invalidate the existing answers is bad. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe '
  unless (s{^\h*name:\K\h*$}{($name,$no) = split " ", <STDIN>; " $name"}e) {
    s{^\h*no:\K\h*$}{ $no}
  }' template < Output.txt
```

Add the `-i` option to edit the `template` file in place instead of producing the result on stdout.

That preserves the `h`orizontal spacing before the `no:` and `name:` if any and replaces the spacing after with a single space and the values retrieved from `Output.txt` (opened on `STDIN`).